# aww4 credentials not accepted when sent via pactjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, pact

I am attempting to verify my pact.json that has been generated by my consumer. However for verifying I need to include AWS4 credentials in order to be able to get a response from my provider. I am attempting to do this using customProviderHeaders. I am using the library AWS4(https://github.com/mhart/aws4) to generate the token. Below is my code:

```
const aws4 = require('aws4');
const path = require('path');
import { before, beforeEach, describe, it } from 'mocha';

const {
    Verifier
} = require('../../../node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact');


function getToken() {
    const opts: any = {
        method: 'GET',
        region: 'us-east-2',
        service: 'execute-api',
        path: '/qa/api/',
        host: '123456789.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    aws4.sign(opts, {accessKeyId: '$AWSACCESSKEY', secretAccessKey: '$AWSSECRETKEY'});
    return opts.headers;
}


describe('Pact Verification', () => {

    it('should validate the watchlist expectations', () => {
        let headers = getToken();
        let  authToken = headers.Authorization;
        let date = headers[`X-Amz-Date`];


        let opts = {
            provider: 'DealerBlock',
            providerBaseUrl: 'https://3ua1cprd53.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
            pactUrls: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/test/pact/path_to_my_json')],
            customProviderHeaders: [`Authorization: ${authToken}`, `X-Amz-Date: ${date}`]
        };

        return new Verifier().verifyProvider(opts)
            .then(output => {
                console.log('STARTED');
                console.log(opts.pactUrls);
                console.log('Pact Verification Complete');
                console.log(output);
            });
    });

});
```

The function getToken() generates a new token and I then grab the token and date and insert them into my request using the customer provider headers.

I see the following:

```
 INFO: Replacing header 'Authorization: ' with 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ5FTCODVMSUTEST/2018908/us-east-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=ceea9aac0303769da58357cb37cb849cb0bbfc13ff0a25cea977385368531349'
 INFO: Replacing header 'X-Amz-Date: ' with 'X-Amz-Date: 20180528T184202Z'
```

However I get the following error:

```
Actual: {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

Am I using the customProviderHeaders in the correct manner? Or does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do differently? I am able to send a request using the same credentials via Postman so not sure whats going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: You sign the request based on the contents of `ops` so the most likely issue is a value changing _after_ you sign the message. For example, if `X-Amz-Date` is part of the signature, changing it after you create the signature would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to my eyes.

Could it be that you're not interpolating the variables (that also appear not to be defined anywhere) in the following statement:

```
aws4.sign(opts, {accessKeyId: '$AWSACCESSKEY', secretAccessKey: '$AWSSECRETKEY'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this working when I passed in headers of:  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' via customProviderHeaders.

Even though this header was listed in my consumer generated json contract, the pact provider did not seem to see it.